# Manifest class with custom permissions is not generated anymore after updating from gradle 2.3.0 to 3.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest, android-studio-3.0

I have some custom permissions in my app, which are usually generated into a Manifest classfile with the corresponding constants. But this classfile is no longer generated when I update my build config in order to use gradle 3.0 (instead of 2.3) with gradle wrapper 4.1. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Important part of my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.myapp.MY_CUSTOM_PERMISSION"
            android:description="somedesc"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="MyCustomPermission"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
```

Expected generated class:

```
public final class Manifest {
    public static final class permission {
      public static final String MY_CUSTOM_PERMISSION="com.myapp.MY_CUSTOM_PERMISSION";
    }
}
```